# Facing issue in .net maui when create a iOS build . Issue is from DevExpress free Control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress, maui

I am using DevExpress Scheduler control for developing "DXCalender" UI. I follow all the steps as mentioned on devexpress site. Its working fine for Android platform but when I am trying to run the same app on iOS it show the exception like as follw

```
 "System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000e from typeref (expected class 'System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation' in assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')
  at at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributesBase(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean )
  at at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider , Type , Boolean )
  at at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type , Boolean )
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ReflectionExtensions.GetCustomAttributesSafe(Assembly assembly, Type attrType)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Assembly[] assemblies, Assembly defaultRendererAssembly, Type[] attrTypes, InitializationFlags flags, Action`1 viewRegistered, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes, InitializationFlags flags, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes, IFontRegistrar fontRegistrar)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.RegisterCompatRenderers(IMauiContext )
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.SetupInit(IMauiContext , Nullable`1 )
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Forms.Init(IActivationState , Nullable`1 )
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__1_1(IMauiContext )
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreatePlatformWindow>b__0(OnMauiContextCreated del)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents[OnMauiContextCreated](IServiceProvider services, Action`1 action)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IApplication application, UIWindowScene windowScene, NSDictionary[] states)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  at at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  at at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 , String[] , IntPtr , IntPtr )
  at at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] , Type , Type )
  at CalmanacMobileAPP.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/apple/Downloads/Vivek/Projects/MobileAPP/Platforms/iOS/Program.cs:13
```

Why that type of exception occur please give me suggestion and solution also
"
register devexpress on mauiprogram.cs file

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseDevExpress()
        .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()                     
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        })

       
        .RegisterAppServices()
        .RegisterAppRepository()
        .RegisterViewModels()
        .RegisterViews()}
```

calendar control UI

```
<dxe:DXCalendar ActiveViewType="Month"  HeightRequest="400" Grid.Row="0" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppWhite}"  x:Name="claender" CustomDayCellAppearance="CustomDayCellAppearance"                       
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ShowTrailingDays="True">
            <dxe:DXCalendar.HeaderAppearance>
                 <dxe:CalendarHeaderAppearance HeaderTitleTextColor="{StaticResource AppBlack}"
                                      HeaderSubtitleTextColor="DimGray"
                                      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppWhite}"/>
            </dxe:DXCalendar.HeaderAppearance>
            <dxe:DXCalendar.DayCellAppearance>
                     <dxe:CalendarDayCellAppearance FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                       SelectedBackgroundColor="#f29285"
                                       SelectedEllipseBackgroundColor="#f29281"
                                       TodayEllipseBackgroundColor="#f29285"/>
            </dxe:DXCalendar.DayCellAppearance>
            
    <dxe:DXCalendar.DayOfWeekCellAppearance>
        <dxe:CalendarDayOfWeekCellAppearance FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" />
    </dxe:DXCalendar.DayOfWeekCellAppearance>         
        </dxe:DXCalendar>
```

also added DevExpress on Package manager also .

Why this was happed please send me a proper solution .

Comment: You've made sure that the DevExpress NuGet feed is added and the packages have been restored correctly? See: https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404024/get-started/register-nuget-gallery

Comment: Yes feed was added already and I am sure all packages were restored correctly

Comment: *"register devexpress on mauiprogram.cs file"* - you have the needed line: `.UseDevExpress()`. From [Build Your First App with DevExpress / Register Handlers for DevExpress Components](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404023/get-started/build-your-first-app#register-handlers-for-devexpress-components).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
 yes already did,but not working still

Comment: I understand. I just mentioned that point so you would know that you have done all there is to do re registration. Contact DevExpress support to resolve the problem.